# How many model fields are too much in a single model django

Tags: python, django, django-models

well I have a doubt, in general you will have many models in a models.py , and that model would have many fields under it(Charfield, foreign key etc...) How many model object are too much in a single model file, for eg if I have 50 model object is it too much? Pls comment your thought on limit for the model object and what's the solution....

Answer (score 1):

The "hard limit" should be very high. But to keep you project structured I'd recommend you to split them into separate apps or model files. There's no recommended number of models per file, but I personally try to stick to max 7 to keep everything organized. You can go higher if you prefer.

You can either structure like this, with separate apps:

```
my_django_project
    manage.py
    app1/
        models.py
    app2/
        models.py
    app3/
        models.py
    my_django_project/
        settings.py
```

or like this within the same app:

```
my_django_project
    manage.py
    app1/
        models/
            __init__.py
            mymodel1.py
            mymodel2.py
            mymodel3.py
    my_django_project/
        settings.py
```

Inside `__init__.py` you have to import all models like this:

```
# __init__.py
from .mymodel1 import *
from .mymodel2 import *
from .mymodel3 import *
```

Which one you choose is up to you. I prefer to have separate apps. And try to keep the in a logically separated, i.e. which models belongs in the same app?

Comment: If I store them separate in different files , what's the difference in that , any performance optimization or just clean code...?

Comment: Just cleaner code, it shouldn't impact performance.

Comment: So what's the max limit for model object

Comment: I'm not sure, you can probably go very very high. You probably don't have to worry about that. But like I said, I'd recommend to split it up with one of my methods to keep it clean.  Like said in the link, there's no limit for max size of a .py file, but you might run out of RAM, so it would depend on your machine. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-maximum-file-size-we-can-open-using-Python